To use Tor with Safari
I try to use Tor with Safari on a Mac.

brew install tor
Safari > Settings > Advanced > Proxies: Change Settings > SOCKS proxy = On > Server = 127.0.0.1 > Port = 9050
brew services start tor

That's it, now Tor works for websites blocked in my country. But how to make it work for onion sites as well? When I try to open them, Safari shows me the "You Are Not Connected to the Internet" page.

Accessing .onion sites on Safari is not straightforward, and definitely not recommended.

.onion sites require Tor DNS resolution, through the Tor network, which is more complicated than just setting up a simple SOCKS proxy.
Now, while you probably could find a way to use Tor's DNS through a different browser, it's still not a good idea.
While a browser such as Safari is still secure, it doesn't take the same (necessary) precautions as does the Tor browser. An example of this is isolation. Within the Tor browser, isolation of everything from networking connections to JS processes is a must.
The Tor network was designed to go hand-in-hand with the Tor browser. Using the two together is, in most cases, the only way you can be safe, and consequently get the privilege of obtaining access to .onion sites.
After all, it's in the Tor project's best interests to keep you safe.

I have created tor.conf with with the SOCKSPort 9150 line there, and then tried to start Tor with tor -f tor.conf (Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay and then nothing) and with brew services start tor -tor.conf (error). Still cannot figure out how to make it work.

I do understand using Safari to access Tor is not secure. It's more an educational thing to me.

In Firefox, the task doesn't seem to be complicated: https://proton.me/support/firefox-onion-sites. I wonder whether something similar exists for Safari.

@jsx97 I’m sure it does, but I’d have to do some research. Thanks for clarifying your intentions, that makes more sense now.
